# Adding OnClick(View v) in a textview

Tags: java, android

i have added onClick in my mainactivity for my textview and i had no errors but when i run the app it crashes saying app has stopped working even though i have no errors in my codes i dont know what's the problem

i hope you can help me and thanks in advance

this is my logcat

```
12-25 03:32:44.694: I/Ads(1433): AdLoader timed out after 60000ms while getting the URL.
12-25 03:33:00.234: I/Process(1433): Sending signal. PID: 1433 SIG: 9
12-25 03:33:38.454: D/dalvikvm(1559): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 40K, 4% free 3135K/3248K, paused 283ms, total 286ms
12-25 03:33:38.504: I/dalvikvm-heap(1559): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.200MB for 1127536-byte allocation
12-25 03:33:38.654: D/dalvikvm(1559): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 3% free 4233K/4352K, paused 146ms, total 146ms
12-25 03:33:39.144: D/dalvikvm(1559): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 3% free 4238K/4352K, paused 46ms, total 47ms
12-25 03:33:39.304: I/dalvikvm-heap(1559): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.535MB for 5591056-byte allocation
12-25 03:33:39.394: D/dalvikvm(1559): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 2% free 9698K/9816K, paused 84ms, total 84ms
12-25 03:33:40.284: V/WebViewChromium(1559): Binding Chromium to the background looper Looper (main, tid 1) {b1d56e50}
12-25 03:33:40.304: I/chromium(1559): [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(112)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
12-25 03:33:40.334: I/BrowserProcessMain(1559): Initializing chromium process, renderers=0
12-25 03:33:40.514: D/(1559): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb7a714f8, tid 1559
12-25 03:33:40.594: W/chromium(1559): [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(888)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
12-25 03:33:41.664: E/ActivityThread(1559): Failed to find provider info for com.google.plus.platform
12-25 03:33:41.774: I/Ads(1559): To get test ads on this device, call adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
12-25 03:33:42.194: D/AndroidRuntime(1559): Shutting down VM
12-25 03:33:42.194: W/dalvikvm(1559): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a83ba8)
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559): Process: imamalsajadsayings.android.com, PID: 1559
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{imamalsajadsayings.android.com/imamalsajadsayings.android.com.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559):     at imamalsajadsayings.android.com.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
12-25 03:33:42.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1559):     ... 11 more
12-25 03:33:43.064: D/dalvikvm(1559): DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'ads478949099.jar' (bootstrap=0) ---
12-25 03:33:46.024: D/dalvikvm(1559): DexOpt: --- END 'ads478949099.jar' (success) ---
12-25 03:33:46.024: D/dalvikvm(1559): DEX prep '/data/data/imamalsajadsayings.android.com/cache/ads478949099.jar': unzip in 54ms, rewrite 2963ms
12-25 03:33:46.844: I/Ads(1559): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://media.admob.com/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_getSdkConstants();AFMA_buildAdURL({"preqs":0,"session_id":"5927457787414134416","seq_num":"1","slotname":"a152b5665edfefd","u_w":384,"msid":"imamalsajadsayings.android.com","cap":"m,a","js":"afma-sdk-a-v6.4.1","bas_off":0,"net":"ed","app_name":"3.android.imamalsajadsayings.android.com","hl":"en","gnt":3,"carrier":"310260","u_audio":4,"kw":[],"u_sd":2,"simulator":1,"ms":"OPbcxzOd9lJImWjXOtp3hqpv26-cVzCC2CRXlOnJL4iR9JnqERa-t0gYOUEDfm9_ZdloVn6JYXvSi2W_T-OmyZGApgUSdoc5Ymf5xM0wqWv4Q1-L-cPGOlLqFb__qZoBPosFpAT3wG8rSE4SjadFbESExgSB07bJ9U3TVzf2AlhGPQR-7N41d3arIEUnV2UCOeer6Y6n_imlZs00ubvpKIcI5sAN2ZBIIoZhg4Qi35EBNf6nHyiKHVecGbgmnf6PDDO1xU1MfLOSdMQeqKZQWyiIsXWPGCBZ6wqyhJmCfeABwzF4p0G6y_gKB2r9xs_HzB4e8lrIQm_l1chnFG96Tg","isu":"B3EEABB8EE11C2BE770B684D95219ECB","format":"320x50_mb","oar":0,"ad_pos":{"height":0,"visible":0,"y":0,"x":0,"width":0},"u_h":592,"pt":1,"bas_on":0,"ptime":0});</script></head><body></body></html>
12-25 03:33:48.574: I/Process(1559): Sending signal. PID: 1559 SIG: 9
```

and this is my MainActivity.java

```
package imamalsajadsayings.android.com;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private LinearLayout someLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
someLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.state2); //layout present in      activity_main
 inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
runNextTask();

 }
 public void runNextTask(){
   LinearLayout mInflatedLayout = (LinearLayout)               inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
 final TrackerInfo newInfo = new TrackerInfo();
    //set up for model selection
    TextView modelTextview = (TextView)mInflatedLayout.findViewById(R.id.state2); 
    someLayout.addView(mInflatedLayout);                   
    modelTextview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

       }
    });
 }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;
  }

   }
```

and this is my activity_main.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

                        <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:orientation="vertical" 
                        android:background="@drawable/images" >



                       <com.google.ads.AdView 
                       android:id="@+id/ad"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
                       ads:adUnitId="a152b5665edfefd"
                       ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
                       ads:adSize="BANNER" />




                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/state1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="قال (عليه السلام): (من كرمت عليه نفسه هانت عليه الدنيا)                                                                         "
                        android:paddingTop="10sp"
                        android:clickable = "false"
                        style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle" />




                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/state2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="قال (عليه السلام): (الخير كله في صيانة الإنسان نفسه)                                                                "
                        android:paddingTop="10sp"             
                        style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
                        android:clickable="true" 
                        android:onClick="runNextTask"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/state3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="قال (عليه السلام): (ما أحب المؤمن معافى في الدنيا، وفي نفسه وماله، ولا يصاب بشيء من المصائب)"
                        android:paddingTop="10sp"
                        android:clickable = "true"
                        style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/state4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text=" قال (عليه السلام): (ضل من ليس له حليم يرشده، وذل من ليس له سفيه يعضده..)                                                "
                        android:paddingTop="10sp"
                        android:clickable = "true"
                        style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/state5"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="قال (عليه السلام): (ويل لمن غلبت آحاده أعشاره)                                                                                         "
                        android:paddingTop="10sp"
                        android:clickable = "true"
                        style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/state6"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="قال (عليه السلام): (اللئيم يأكل ماله الأعداء، والذي خبث لا يخرج إلا نكداً..)                                                 "
                        android:paddingTop="10sp"
                        android:clickable = "true"
                        style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"/>

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/view3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/state7"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="       قال (عليه السلام): (إن الجسد إذا لم يمرض يأشر ولا خير في جسد يأشر..)                                                                       "
                        android:paddingTop="10sp"
                        android:clickable = "true"
                        style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/state8"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="قال (عليه السلام): (عليكم بأداء الأمانة، فوالذي بعث محمداً بالحق نبياً لو أن قاتل أبي الحسين بن علي ائتمنني على السيف الذي قتله به لأديته إليه..)"
                        android:paddingTop="10sp"
                        android:clickable = "true"
                        style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/state9"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="قال (عليه السلام): (أفضل الأعمال عند الله ما عمل بالسنة)                                                                   "
                        android:paddingTop="10sp"
                        android:clickable = "true"
                        style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/state9"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="قال (عليه السلام): (لقد استرقك بالود من سبقك بالشكر..)                                                                              "
                        android:paddingTop="10sp"
                        android:clickable = "true"
                        style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/state10"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="قال (عليه السلام): (لا يكون الصديق صديقاً حتى يقطع لأخيه المؤمن قطعة من دينه يرقعها بالاستغفار..)"
                        android:paddingTop="10sp"
                        android:clickable = "true"
                        style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/state11"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="قال (عليه السلام): (ضمنت على ربي أنه لا يسال أحد من غير حاجة إلا اضطرته المسألة يوماً إلى أن يسأل من حاجة..)"
                        android:paddingTop="10sp"
                        android:clickable = "true"
                        style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/state12"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="قال (عليه السلام): (إياك، وما تعتذر منه)                                                                                                                  "
                        android:paddingTop="10sp"
                        android:clickable = "true"
                        style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/state13"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="قال (عليه السلام): (إن الله جل جلاله يقول: وعزتي وعظمتي وجمالي، وبهائي، وعلوي، وارتفاع مكان لا يؤثر عبد هواي على هواه إلا جعلت همه في آخرته، وغناه في قلبه، كففت عنه ضيعته، وضمنت السماوات والأرض رزقه، وأتته الدنيا وهي راغمة)"
                        android:paddingTop="10sp"
                        android:clickable = "true"
                        style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"/>

                     <TextView
                         android:id="@+id/state14"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="قال (عليه السلام): (رب مغرور، مفتون، يصبح لاهياً ضاحكاً، يأكل ويشرب، وهو لا يدري لعله قد سبقت له من الله سخطه، يصلى بها نار جهنم..)"
                        android:paddingTop="10sp"
                        android:clickable = "true"
                        style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"/>



        </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Post your code also because it clearly says that java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout

Comment: Your code it totally messy. Are you sure you are an android developer.

Comment: also remove `android:onClick="runNextTask"` attribute from TextView xml because you are adding click listener in code

Comment: here `someLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.state2);` to are casting TextView to LinearLayout

Comment: @user3115742 Check out my answer and try with that code. I have done some relevant changes in your code.

Answer (score 2):

You have wrongly initialized your `TextView` As you have added `TextView` in your layout and you are trying to initialize it with `LinearLayout` which is wrong.

Change the `LinearLayout` with `TextView` in your onCreate() as below :

```
 someLayout = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.state2);
```

Why are you inflating your layout two times in your code ? I do not understand why are you doing so. But i am providing the code with some relevant code try with my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private TextView someLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       someLayout = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.state2); //layout present in      activity_main
      // inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     runNextTask();

 }
 public void runNextTask(){
       //  LinearLayout mInflatedLayout = (LinearLayout)               inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
      @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    final TrackerInfo newInfo = new TrackerInfo();
    //set up for model selection
   // TextView modelTextview = (TextView)mInflatedLayout.findViewById(R.id.state2); 
    //someLayout.addView(mInflatedLayout);                   
    someLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

       }
    });
 }
```

FYI You can not add any layout in `TextView` as its `View` not a `Layout` and in your code i have seen that you are trying to add `Layout` into `View` which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
public void runNextTask(View v){ // method signature is worng
```

Also if textView is in activity_main.xml. There is no need to inflate the layout

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // is enough
```

And initialize textView in onCreate

```
TextView modelTextview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.state2);
```

If you want to have click listener progrmatically remove

```
android:onClick="runNextTask"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your id for linear layout and text-view both are same or what, if it is so, then change the id of linear layout. by below line of code it is clear that you have assigned same id to linear layout and text-view.

```
someLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.state2);
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is here `someLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.state2);`

you are trying to cast textview to linearlayout.

use   `yourtextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.state2);`